# Symfony 3.4 - Dependency Injection for ResettingController of FosUserBundle work only in dev env

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

My initial problem is this error:

> Too few arguments to function
> FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController::__construct(), 0 passed
> in
> /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php
> on line 200 and exactly 6 expected

that happens when i open the link in the automatic Mail of FosUserBundle [FOSMailer](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Mailer/MailerInterface.php)::sendResettingEmailMessage

```
// routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:
      /{_locale}/
    requirements:
      _locale: fr|en|es

app_api:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/Api"
    type:     annotation

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

fos_user_security_login:
    path: /connexion
    methods:  [ GET, POST ]
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user_security_check:
    path: /login_check
    methods:  [ POST ]
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

fos_user_security_logout:
    path: /logout
    methods:  [ GET, POST ]
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }

fos_user_resetting_reset:
    path: /resetting/reset/{token}
    methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Resetting:reset }
```

I cleared the cache, and i added the 6 parameters with dependency injection:

```
//services.yml

services:
  fos_user.resetting.reset:
    class: FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController
    arguments:
      - "@event_dispatcher"
      - "@fos_user.resetting.form.factory"
      - "@fos_user.user_manager"
      - "@fos_user.util.token_generator"
      - "@fos_user.mailer"
      - "%fos_user.resetting.retry_ttl%"
```

That worked well in dev environnement (in local and on a server), but i still got the same error "too few arguments..." in production.

So cleared the cache again : `bin/console c:c --env=prod`

removed the cache folder: `rm -Rf var/cache/prod`

But i still got the error :/
Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: FOSUserBundle?  Wow.  Blast from the past.  Change `_controller: FOSUserBundle:Resetting:reset` to `fos_user.resetting.reset`.  Basically the route definition needs to use the controller's service id.  You could also do the opposite and use the controller's class name as the service id.

Comment: Doesn't work either

Comment: There is a section in the docs that discusses using controllers as services.  It will have an example.  Be sure to use the 3.4 version of the docs.  You might need something like `fos_user.resetting.reset::reset` Note the double colon.  It's been so long, I forget the details.  `app/console debug:router` might also help.

Comment: By using `fos_user.resetting.reset` (with or without ::reset) the controller is not found.
So i tried it with the real path of the controller : `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController::reset`, and this time the controller is found, but it returned the same error as before (Too few arguments ...)
@Cerad still thank you for your help

Comment: Try `bin/console debug:container ResettingController` to see if the FOSUserBundle is defining it as a service.  It is probably being defined some place.  The request handle first looks for a matching service in the container.  If not found then it uses new to make a controller instance which results in the constructor error.  And make sure that if you do find a service that it is public.  And what exactly do you mean when you say `controller is not found`?  Are you getting a different error message?

Comment: When i try `bin/console debug:container ResettingController`, it returns : 
`No services found that match "ResettingController".`
And yes, `"controller is not found"` is the error i get by using `fos_user.resetting.reset` : `"Controller not found: service "fos_user.resetting.reset" does not exist."`

And i should have tell that before, but i use other FosUserBundle functions that works well ... there is a problem only with Resetting:reset (i'll update the routing.yml file in my question)

Comment: Just for kicks, does `bin/console debug:container fos_user.resetting` show anything useful?  Or even just grep `debug:container` for the word resetting.  'reset' is the controller action name so it would not be part of the service id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Cerad for your help.
I finally found the solution to my problem :

i just realized that the version of fosUserBundle wasn't the same on the 2 servers ...

so i just changed my composer.json with that:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*"
```

And this works fine!